# git restore of an actually unchanged folder

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a modified folder (whyever, I can't figure out any chances on it) and want to unstage (and keep) its content because it is a submodule here with codes inside.

```
C:\Users\devuser\source\repos\MainProject>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   SubProject (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So far I know I can unstage it with `git restore SubProject`. If I say `git restore SubProject` I get still

```
C:\Users\devuser\source\repos\MainProject>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   SubProject (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

After a while of research I stuck with this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the message SubProject (new commits) means that at this one moment in time your superproject tracks that submodule at an older commit than the most recent one available. You probably got the newest from a remote server. There is nothing to revert to :) Git is just telling you that your submodule has new updates. Do you want to track those new updates, or do you prefer to have the submodule in the state it is now?

Comment: @DaemonPainter: No, the situation isn't as trivial as it seems. After a while working on this repository I got the same incident again (working on another project).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit: The first solution was just temporary. I got the same issue again working on this repo.

Permanant solution: I figured out the `SubProject`  was a former git repo which was **integrated later** into the MainProject.

The SubProject had a `.git` folder by its own, since it was always complaining untracked changes for each time compiling the whole project.

So I deleted `.git` folder in the SubProject and got the right status back checking with `git status`.

I keep the temporary solution striked out (could be helpful for another one).

Temporary solution:
<s>The solution was to add the folder to the main project.</s>

```
C:\Users\devuser\source\repos\MainProject>git add SubProject

C:\Users\devuser\source\repos\MainProject>git add SubProject/

C:\Users\devuser\source\repos\MainProject>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   SubProject
```

And then I commited it pushed it to the repo.

```
C:\Users\devuser\source\repos\MainProject>git commit -m "SubProject was unstaged?!"
[master 1042efc] SubProject was unstaged?!
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

C:\Users\devuser\source\repos\MainProject>git push
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 266 bytes | 266.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Analyzing objects... (2/2) (196 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (54 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (48 ms)
To https://my.repo.com/DefaultCollection/MainProject/_git/MainProject
   b901854..1042efc  master -> master
```

Checking again with `git status` I got

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Summary: I assume I only added the SubProject but not t-o-g-e-t-h-e-r with the MainProject.